# Modelise tournament application with cake php

Tags: sql, cakephp, uml, tournament

I want to create a tournament application with cakePHP and I need some help to create Database and linking Models correctly.

My ultimate goal is :

```
- add/edit/delete teams (i dont need list of players)
- add/edit/delete matchs with 2 teams per match
- display a list of match with results (ex:  match5 : TeamAname **2** vs **0** TeamBname)
```

I dont really know how to organise models and sql tables, for the moment i see 2 tables :

```
- teams
- matches
```

Did i need another table between the two tables (ex: matches_teams) or i can use teamA_id and teamB_id  in my matches table ? Does CakePHP support multiple foreign keys in same model  ?

I want to know if someone has already developed this kind of project in cakePHP, and if it work fine and logically (without tricks).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*> Do i need another table between the two tables (ex: matches_teams) or i can use teamA_id and teamB_id in my matches table?*

You don't need another (association) table, because the only associations you have are the two many-to-one associations between `matches` and `teams` given by the two reference columns `teamA_id` and `teamB_id` of `matches`.

In terms of the ontological semantics of the domain of sports, the entity type `Match` represents an event type, while the entity type `Team` represents an object type. And for each event of type `Match` you have two objects of type `Team` participating in it.

*> Does CakePHP support multiple foreign keys in same model?*

It would be quite limited if it wouldn't.